# Undeclared variable in C while it has been declared

Tags: c, eclipse

I created a for-loop in C, which should work, Eclipse however told me that I used an undeclared variable, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    printf("i is %d\n", i);
}
return 0;
}
```

according to Eclipse the undeclared variable, is `i` on the `printf` line it has been declared in the `for` statement right? This code is the exact same code as used in the tutorial I am following, it did work in the video though.

Comment: your compiler is probably following C89 rules, where you have to declare variables after the start of a new block { see if you can configure eclipse to use C99 or put the int i; right after main(){

Comment: Thanks robin.koch! Changing Eclipse to use C99 did indeed work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ANSI C (unlike C90/C11) you cannot declare variables in for loop. You unfortunatelly have to to this (or change your compiler to a more modern one, you won't be compatible with the ANSI standard though):

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
int i;
for(i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    printf("i is %d\n", i);
}
return 0;
}
```